# How to use Javascript array as template in HTML table element

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

New to all this and could use a little help, please.
I have an array that looks something like this:

`contactArray = [{"Name":"Blake Janacek","Title":"Marketing Manager"},{"Name":"Dominic Flanders","Title":"Project Manager"}];`

I'm trying to display a table with headers repeating each array object like this:

```
<table id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Title</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <div id="list"></div>
     <template id="template">
       <tr>
         <td>{name}</td>
         <td>{title}</td>
       </tr>
     </template>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem I'm having is the data from the array is displaying above the header and not formatted. Here's what I'm trying:

```
const html = contactArray.map(obj => {
                let item = document.querySelector('#template').innerHTML;
                item = item.replace('{name}', obj.Name);
                item = item.replace('{title}', obj.Title);
                return item;
                });
                document.querySelector('#list').innerHTML = html.join('');
```

Thank you

Oh, and here's a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/t69bz54o/

Comment: A `<div>` is not allowed inside a `<tbody>` element. So instead remove it and set the ID on the body itself like: `<tbody id="list">`

Comment: Gosh. I was hoping it would be something simple. Thanks much, Reyno! Problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have a `div` outside of a `tr` element inside a `table`.
You can achieve the same by assigning the `#list` id to the `tbody` element instead, like this:

```html
 <table id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Title</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="list">
     <template id="template">
       <tr>
         <td>{name}</td>
         <td>{title}</td>
       </tr>
     </template>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

The JS should work as-is. Although there could be some performance improvements such as preloading the template DOM before the loop, so search is not done multiple times

Comment: oh, I forgot, since you are replacing the content inside the `tbody`, the template will disappear so it cannot longer be used. I hope that is OK with your use case

Answer (score 1):

### Html part

```
<table id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Title</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="list">
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

### JavaScript Part

```
contactArray = [{"Name":"Blake Janacek","Title":"Marketing Manager"},{"Name":"Dominic Flanders","Title":"Project Manager"}]; 

const html = contactArray.map(obj => {
                return ('<tr><td>'+obj.Name+'</td><td>'+obj.Title+'</td></tr>')
                }).join('');
document.querySelector('#list').innerHTML = html;
```

The above code works fine, but there is the need for some CSS tricks for alignment.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers will probably work as expected. I would still like to point out that with the template literals in ES6 you can achieve the same effect in an easier way:

```js
const contactArray = [
 {Name:"Blake Janacek",Title:"Marketing Manager"},
 {Name:"Dominic Flanders",Title:"Project Manager"} ];
 
document.querySelector("#dataTable tbody").innerHTML=
  contactArray.map(({Name,Title})=>
   `<tr>
      <td>${Name}</td>
      <td>${Title}</td>
    </tr>`).join("\n");
```

```html
<table id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Title</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The template literal is supplied directly in the JavaScript code section.